# How to make C-c C-e to not add a new line at the end in AUCTeX

Tags: auctex

I do not like how a newline is added when I add a new environment using <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> in AUCTeX. This is especially annoying when I use <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> to insert an environment within math mode (e.g. `cases` environment) within an `align` environment because then I have to delete that newline to avoid getting a compile error. Is there a way I can turn off "add new line after <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>" when in math mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUCTeX way of inserting environments with <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> was improved with [this change](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/latex.el?id=f2bac9dcde12d939a5c1267fdba02c2a869bd406).  Which AUCTeX version are you using?  Please update your installation (easily done via ELPA) and try it again.

Comment: Yup, the update solved the problem. Thanks!